# How to connect a component to the redux store and Apollo client at the same time

Tags: reactjs, redux, apollo

I am trying to integrate an Apollo client to my react js application.

My application integrate already Redux and I want to avoid writing a code like this :

```
export default graphql(HELLO_QUERY)(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HelloForm));
```

Is there a cleanner manner to connect my component to the Apollo Client and the Redux at the same time

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/apollo-docs-1.x/redux.html   ??

Comment: It doesnt work as the document is for the V1 of apollo. I m using V2.1.1